# Execute multiple shell scripts of same name under several sub-directories

Tags: bash, shell, deployment

I am using a shell script from a parent directory to call multiple other shell scripts, all having the same name, but under separate subdirectories. Let me elaborate below:

```
Parent directory: Script deploy_modules.sh
SubDir A: deploy.sh
SubDir B: deploy.sh
SubDir C: deploy.sh
....
SubDir Z: deploy.sh
```

The script deploy_modules.sh calls each of the sub-directory's deploy.sh sequentially by entering that directory, calling the script, then exiting and entering the next one.

Is there a way to sequentially execute all the deploy.sh files in a single line command? I need the command to be generic enough to automatically include any newly added sub-directory with another deploy.sh, and not give error if one or more of the sub-directories are removed.

Comment: Why does it have to be in a single line? It just makes it hard to read.

Comment: A single line is not a hardcore requirement, I just mentioned that to mean that it shouldn't be much longer. The primary requirement is it being generic and being able to execute fine when new directories are added or existing ones are removed.

Comment: Ok, that's good. Hope my answer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would find all `deploy.sh` scripts in the subdirectories to wherever the current directory is - and execute them.

Without doing `cd` down into the subdirectories:

```
for dep in */deploy.sh; do "$dep"; done
```

Doing `cd` down into each subdirectory:

```
for dep in */deploy.sh; do (cd "$(dirname "$dep")"; ./deploy.sh) done
```

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: I tried the second one, and it worked. In this particular use case, the shell instance needs to be inside the directory when the deploy.sh of that directory is being executed.

Comment: @AviBis I see, great!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
find Parentdir -maxdepth 1 -name deploy.sh -exec {} \;
```

Omit the `maxdepth` option, if you want to include deploy scripts further down in your tree as well.

In case you need to execute the deployment script from inside the directory it is in (though you don't mention this in your question), use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`.

Comment: What do you mean by `did not work`? What would a `find Parentdir -maxdepth 1` show? You need to provide a bit more feedback if you want help here.  `find` should locate the files; of course you may need to adapt the `-exec` command to suit your requirements.

Comment: This didn't work not because your script is wrong, but because in this particular use case, the shell instance needs to be inside the directory when the deploy.sh of that directory is being executed.